# Yoga 3 hangs randomly

Tags: lenovo

I have a Yoga 3 Pro, I've been using it with the latest official Ubuntu release (18.04, 18.10, 19.04, 19.10). Recently (about half a year ago) it started freezing randomly. Sometimes it works for some minutes sometimes for some hours. I downgraded to 18.04 yesterday but it's still freezing.

Last time I was using my phone to connect via SSH and run `sudo journalctl -xe -f`. As my desktop had stopped working I checked the journal but I could see nothing meaningful (no errors, warnings). The SSH connection was broken too (so it's not only the GUI that dies). I'm pretty interested in what the heck it could be.

Could anybody help me how to do diagnose? Thanks!

UPDATE:
My notebook works again. I physically had pressed and twisted the case here and there a little and the WiFi card was not functioning anymore. So I have the WiFi card changed now and everything seems perfect since then. I'm not closing the case though because I'm still interested if I could have narrowed down this issue with testing and diagnosing (instead of torturing) Any idea? :)

Comment: Latest official?  Why have you listed multiple releases?  Have you ruled out hardware? (ie. memtest & running a different OS via live using something very different?, or assuming outside of warranty, a cap-check?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! As you said it appears to be a I hardware error... the WiFi adapter looks suspicious to me. I think I will take it to a computer doc.. (for your question I have used many releases through the years, and for a while I haven't got such an issue. Now I have it even after reinstall of 18.04.4... I haven't try it with other OS (windows is a bit out of my reach now))

Comment: With other OSes I wasn't thinking about windows, I'd try opensuse, fedora, maybe even a BSD to see if they have the same responses as if it's hardware I would expect the same on any OS, and 'live' allows you to quickly test other systems without install.  (I'd also try and get different ages of software stack, eg. 18.04 is 2018-April with 4.15 kernel, so in another I'd go for something different with a different kernel & release-date...)